# Creating Hotspot while remaining connected to WI-FI

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, hot-spot

Is there any way create a Hotspot network in Ubuntu machine while still remaining connected to wi-fi.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a a solution to having both a HotSpot and a WiFi connection *regardless of the OS, including Ubuntu* (and it's the only solution there is) and that is to:

- have 2 WiFi cards

(one used as a HotSpot and the other to connect to the WiFi)

<sub>Probably not what you wanted to hear, but it's the only correct answer there is, *unfortunately...*</sub>

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer before on this site, if the answer helped you, don't forget to click the little grey checkmark next to the answer, turning it a beautiful green...  **;-)**

Comment: I think I can plug my phone into the laptop USB port and it can create a hot spot but I haven't tried this. I do know the phone can create a WiFi hot spot whilst connected to cell network though.

Comment: And the phone runs Ubuntu?  :)  @WinEunuuchs2Unix ;)

Comment: The laptop certainly is, unless nVIDIA breaks things then I have to reboot with Windows 8 to look up repair instructions :)

Comment: Then how they do it in windows. I mean, on windows to can be connected to wi-fi network and create a hotspot at same time even if your machine have only one wi-fi card..... I just ask out of  curiosity, it's ok if you consider that off-topic.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Would you like to take over?  Will delete my answer if yours can give a working solution... (upstart & systemd)  **:-)**

Comment: @fabby It was a comment but I don't think using cell phone is acceptable to OP anyways. No you are doing great... Please carry on Fabby :)